# Can a liquid with angle of contact as 90 degrees with a solid surface definitely wet it?

Tags: surface-tension

Can we conclusively say something about wetting conditions at this boundary value of angle of contact ($90^o$)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is some degree of wetting if the angle is <180 degree.  Only 180 degree contact angle represents no wetting.